# Emulator Preview not showing in Jetpack Compose like Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying learn jectpack compose , and I Want to see also Emulator in Preview , but emulator not showing . this is my picture [image]

what I should to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your combinable functions as a preview as in your image.

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]